# ASP.Net MVC2 - IIS7.5 doesn't find view file for home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

We have a mid-sized asp.net project that we just promoted from our dev server (Windows 2003) to an external test server (Windows 2008 R2).

On the test server, IIS is not finding our home page, which is located in the views/home folder (404 error).  As far as we can tell, the settings are the same on both servers.  I've confirmed HTTP redirection is installed.

Is there perhaps some critical configuration we may have missed on IIS7.5 to let it know where to find the view and/or home page?

Comment: http://arturito.net/2011/01/21/publishing-asp-net-mvc2-application-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7-with-visual-studio-2008-on-platform-net-3-5-sp1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the App Pool for 4 classic to 4, seemed to fix the 404 issue.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not finding"? Are you getting 404 error?

I had a similar situation which was related with bad install of ASP.NET on windows 7 machine, so I would recommend you to:

1. Check if ASP.NET is installed on server
2. Run [aspnet_regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx) to check that ASP.NET correctly registered with IIS

Comment: Yes its a 404 error.  I can check that, but other asp.net apps on the server seem to work fine, will double check.